# Does Varnish-devicedetect cookie based User-agent override require vary: cookie for correct browser caching?

Tags: caching, cookies, user-agent, varnish, http-caching

[varnish-devicedetect](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-devicedetect/blob/master/devicedetect.vcl) lets me return different responses based on User-agent:

```
...
elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)ipad")        { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-ipad"; }
elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)ip(hone|od)") { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-iphone"; }
...
```

and lets users opt into a different device experience by setting a cookie:

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(?i)X-UA-Device-force") {
  ...
}
```

Do I need to add `Vary: Cookie` to get correct client caching behavior?

For example:

1. I set only `Vary: User-agent`
2. A user browses to example.com/beep
3. They opt into the desktop experience, setting `X-UA-Device-force: pc`.
4. They reload example.com/beep.
   Will their browser use the cached mobile version, since only Cookies, not User-agent changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to set a `Vary: Cookie` header to get the correct behaviour since different cookies would retrive different output.

You'll need also to take care of the cookie on `vcl_recv` setting the appropriate `X-UA-Device` in order to hash items correctly in varnish.

Answer (score 0):

If you vary cookie, then you might as well throw caching out the window since most users will have different cookies (especially so if you have any analytics on your site) so you will have a low hit rate and multiple copies of the same data in your cache.

Rather than vary cookie, do a hash on the specific cookie value like so:

```
if (req.http.cookie ~ "(?i)X-UA-Device-force" ) {
  hash_data("deviceforce");
} else {
  hash_data("nodeviceforce");
}
```

Comment: Agreed, Vary: Cookie is not great.  I believe you could get a decent hit rate by being very careful with the cookies sent from the same domain.  Analytics cookies are usually set for the domain of the analytics service (google.com for example) and shouldn't impact caching from our app domain, no?

Comment: Hashing on a specific cookie makes total sense in varnish.  How might you communicate cacheability to downstream clients, like the browser?  Seems like the only options are include `Vary: cookie`, or `no-cache` to the response from varnish...  Are there other options?